# react-native expo : how to upload image to firebase storage

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, react-native-firebase

I am building an app with firebase .
I had successfully implemented a function that will enable the user to upload a  pic to firebase storage
here it is

```
  const uploadImageToBucket = async () => {
    let blob;
    try {
      setUploading(true);
      blob = await getPictureBlob(image);

      const ref = await storage.ref().child(uuid.v4());
      const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);

      return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e.message);
    } finally {
      blob.close();
      setUploading(false);
    }
  };
```

the problem is that I want the picture to be uploaded based on certain user and I want to set that pic as user profile pic .any suggestion please!!

Comment: Do you know UID of that user and are you trying to set the `photoURL` in Firebase Auth of that user?

Comment: yup exactly . sure I know the user uid because the user is already signed up

Comment: Just to confirm what do you mean by 'certain user'? You are trying to set photoURL from currently logged in user after uploading the image ?

Comment: yuh that is why I meanst

Answer (score 0):

here the user sign up function

```
  const handleSignUp = () => {
    setErrortext("");
    if (!FullName) return alert("Please fill Name");
    if (!Email) return alert("Please fill Email");
    if (!Password) return alert("Please fill Address");
    setIsLogged(true);
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password)
      .then((user) => {
        alert("Registration Successful. Please Login to proceed");
        console.log(user);
        if (user) {
          firebase
            .auth()
            .currentUser.updateProfile({
              displayName: FullName,
            })
            .then(() => navigation.replace("Log_In"))
            .then(() => {
              firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((userData) => {
                setuserData(userData);
              });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              setErrortext(error);
            });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
          setErrortext("That email address is already in use!");
          setIsLogged(false);
        } else {
          setErrortext(error.message);
          setIsLogged(false);
        }
      });
  };
```

Comment: If you are giving additional details on your question then you should edit the question and add them instead of adding the details as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `updateProfile` method to update currently logged in user's photoURL and set it to the download URL just requested. The `uploadImageToBucket` function returns that URL back so you can try this:

```js
uploadImageToBucket().then(async (photoURL) => {
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
  await user.updateProfile({ photoURL })
  console.log("Photo URL updated")
})
```

Comment: I did not get ur point clearly. Can you explain more please.

Comment: @houcinolmostaf can you try copying my code? Wherever you are calling upload image function,  call the updateProfile method after that

Comment: I didn't get ur point clearly. Can you explain more please. Or just link the example u gave me with code I have provided in the question above